# Add few records to gridview from DataTable

Tags: c#

I have been working on asp.net/C# project. I could bind the DataTable to gridview. But  i have a situation where i don't want to bind all the records in DataTable. is there any method to bind only few records to gridview?  any Alternatives to GridView.DataBind()?

Thank you

Comment: what kind of restrictions you want to put in that to bind few records??

Comment: Suppose i have DataTable with student records, i want to select Students who opted subject "maths", and bind these records to a GridView. Hope u understood, Thank you

Comment: than you can do select on your datatable for that condition and give that source to gridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

using datatable select query you can achieve this,
for example,

```
DataTable dt=yourdata;
DataRow[] dr=dt.Select("columnname='Maths'");

foreach (DataRow row in dr) {
   dt.ImportRow(row);
}
GridView1.DataSource=dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

where Maths = your search criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the rows manually, i.e. without using a data source.

```
var newRowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Add(firstValue, secondValue, thirdValue);
```

You might use it like this:

```
foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in myDataTable.Rows)
{
    if(meets my criteria...)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row["Column1"], row["Column2"], row["Column3"]);
    }
}
```

In fact, this may be a better solution as it allows you to sort columns easily in the UI whereas binding to a data source does not allow that.

Answer (score 0):

Use DataView for the DataTable, So that you can able to filter records and assign the dataview to Grid.

for example:

```
DataView dv = new DataView(DataTable, "Column1=Value", "Column2", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```